# Trying to run an echo statement with lolcat animation while a boot music should be running when the animation is running

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, termux

I'm trying to run a bash script but can't figure out how to run 2 commands at the same time while they are giving me the output at the very same time.

```
#!/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash
  #
 
  command_not_found_handle() {
        /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/libexec/termux/command-not-found "$1"
    }
    tput civis
 
    clear
   echo
   echo "
                    < ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ [★] T E R M U X [★] ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ >  " |lolcat -d 10 -a

  echo


  echo
  figlet -f ASCII-Shadow '     123456' |lolcat -a -d 5
  # txt file to add a user define variable to bash.bashcr
  # display ipv4 address of user
 currentDate=`date`
 echo $currentDate | lolcat
  myip=$(ifconfig | grep 'inet' | grep -v '::1' | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | awk NR==1'{print $2}')

  echo "
                   < ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ [★] $myip [★] ━━━━━━━━━━━━━ > " |lolcat
  echo
  tput cnorm
```

I want the the music file and the animation to run at the same time, could anyone kindly please suggest me changes for my code?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can launch the music into the background, capture it's PID and when the animation is done kill the music.

```bash
your-music-player &
music_pid=$!

# lolcat stuff here

kill "$music_pid"
```